# Загрузка последней Activity, на которой остановился пользователь

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение с загадками (загадки, дедукция и логика), как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "загадки" открывалась страница с загадкой на которой остановился пользователь, чтоб ему не приходилось заново отвечать на все загадки?

Comment: пишите в файл или базу, а затем восстанавливайте по ним процесс

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что нужно использовать SharedPreferences:
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html

Comment: Тоесть активити, которая выводит вопрос одна, а с помощью SharedPreferences ты можешь выводить вопрос на котором остановился перед закрытием приложения.